Calculating a Conditional expectation
My question is the following. Given that we have $n$ i.i.d. random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ with distribution $f(x)=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}x\mathbf{1}_{[0,\lambda]}(x)$, where $\lambda> 0$ is some parameter, how do I calculate the the conditional expectation
$$E[X_i|X_{\max}],$$
with $X_{\max}=\max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$. My idea was writing $X_i=X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i=X_{\max}\}}+X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i<X_{\max}\}}$. But this only left me with
$$E[X_i|X_{\max}]=X_{\max}\mathbb{P}(X_i=X_{\max}|X_{\max})+E[X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i<X_{\max}\}}|X_{\max}],$$
which doesn't really gelp me I think. I've been given one hint: In the end we should have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i|X_{\max}]=\frac{2n+1}{3}X_{\max},$$
So my guess is
$$E[X_i|X_{\max}]=\frac{2n+1}{3n}X_{\max}.$$
Any suggestions on how to proceed are welcome. Thank you.

This can be found using the same arguments as used here and its linked posts.


But this only left me with
$$E[X_i|X_{\max}]=X_{\max}\mathbb{P}(X_i=X_{\max}|X_{\max})+E[X_i\mathbf{1}_{\{X_i<X_{\max}\}}|X_{\max}],$$
which doesn't really gelp me I think.

Mixing the notation slightly, we may also write that as:
$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_i\mid X_\max) & = {{X_\max\,\mathsf P(X_i{\,=\,}X_\max\mid X_\max)}+{\mathsf E(X_i:{X_i<X_\max}\mid X_\max)\,\mathsf P(X_i{\,<\,}X_\max\mid X_\max)}}\end{align}$
Now, what are those probability masses?   Easy!   Since each of the $n$ samples is independent and identically distributed, each has the same probability for being the maximum.
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_i{\,=\,}X_\max\mid X_\max)~&=~1/n\\\mathsf P(X_i{\,<\,}X_\max\mid X_\max)~&=~(n-1)/n\end{align}$
So therefore:
$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X_i\mid X_\max] & = {{X_\max\,\mathsf P(X_i=X_\max\mid X_\max)}+{\mathsf E(X_i:{X_i<X_\max}\mid X_\max)\,\mathsf P(X_i<X_\max\mid X_\max)}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{X_\max}n+\dfrac{\int_{x<X_\max} xf_{X}(x)\,\mathrm d x}{\int_{x<X_\max}f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x}\cdot\dfrac{n-1}{n}\\[2ex] &~\vdots\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{(1+2n)X_\max}{3n}\end{align}$
You should complete the work yourself to verify the result.

Let $V=\max\{X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$. For $0\leq v\leq \lambda$ we have
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  F_V(v) &=& \Pr(V \leqslant v) = \Pr(\max\{X_2,\ldots,X_n\} \leqslant v) \\ &=& \Pr(X_2 \leqslant v,\ldots,X_n \leqslant v) \\ &=& F_X(v)^{n-1} = \left(\dfrac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{2n-2}
\end{eqnarray}$$
And so $f_V(v)=\dfrac{2n-2}{\lambda^{2n-2}}x^{2n-3}$ for $0\leq v\leq \lambda$.
Now, notice that $X_{\max}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}=\max\{X_1,V \}$ (with $X_1$ and $V$ independent).
Therefore, \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_{\max}=y) &=& \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid \max\{X_1,V\}=y) \\ &=& \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid \max\{X_1,V\}=y,X_1 \leqslant V) \Pr(X_1 \leqslant V) + \\ && \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid \max\{X_1,V\}=y,X_1 > V) \Pr(X_1>V) \\
&=& \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid V=y, X_1\leqslant V) \Pr(X_1 \leqslant V)  + \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_1=y,X_1>V) \Pr(X_1>V)
\end{eqnarray}
You can compute these quantities (remember that $X_1$ and $V$ are independent): $$\mathsf{E}(X_1\mid V=y, X_1\leqslant V)=\mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_1\leqslant y)=\dfrac{2y}{3}$$ $$\Pr(X_1 \leqslant V)=\dfrac{2n-2}{2n}$$ $$\mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_1=y,X_1>V)=\mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_1=y)=y$$ $$\Pr(X_1>V)=\dfrac{1}{n}$$
This means that $$ \mathsf{E}(X_1\mid X_{\max}=y)=\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}y=\dfrac{2n+1}{3n}X_{\max}$$
Given that the $X_i$ are i.i.d, we get that $$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i\mid X_{\max}]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_1\mid X_{\max}]=\dfrac{2n+1}{3}X_{\max}$$
